# Connect to a database from Azure Website using Integrated Security

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to use Integrated Security when connection to a SQL Server from Azure Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do that. Azure WebSite servers are stand-alone server, out of your control. To use Windows Authentication (integrated security) your need to share the same AD (or trusted domains) between the IIS server and the Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, Azure SQL Database does not support Azure AD authentication.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Integrated Security is for when you want to use Windows Authentication, which is not possible with Azure SQL database.

You must create a login/user and use SQL authentication to connect to a Azure SQL database.

PS: make sure you've also whitelisted the IP address from where you want to connect.